# Why does python generator result like this?

Tags: python, list, generator

Here's the code:

```
def is_subsequence(a, b):
    b = iter(b)
    
    gen = ((i in b) for i in a)
    print(gen)

    for i in gen:
        print(i)

    return all(((i in b) for i in a))

res1 = is_subsequence([1, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
res2 = is_subsequence([1, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

The result is that `res1==False` and `res2==False`. Apparently the result for `res1` is incorrect.
When I comment out the for loop print, `res1==True` and `res2==False`, which is correct.
I'm confused. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Because you already consumed the iterator `b` when `for i in gen:...`. If you separate iterators for each generators like, `b, c = iter(b), iter(b)` and `return all(((i in c) ...)` will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generators are lazy iterators. You can loop over them like a list but once you do, they are exhausted, i.e. nothing is left. With the following line,

```
gen = ((i in b) for i in a)
print(gen)
```

you create a generator object and then with the following loop,

```
for i in gen:
    print(i)
```

you exhaust it. Incidentally you also exhaust `b` while exhausting `gen`. So by the time of the last line, `b` is empty, so your function will always return False.

IIUC, you want to evaluate if `a` is a subsequence (not subset) of `b`. So the order matters. You can change your function to:

```
def is_subsequence(a, b):
    b = iter(b)
    return all(((i in b) for i in a))
```

and it will work as intended.

Output:

```
res1 = is_subsequence([1, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  # True
res2 = is_subsequence([1, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  # False
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue you have is with the expression `i in b` when `b` is an iterator. Checking membership in an iterator iterates over the values. It returns `True` if the value gets found (consuming values from the iterator up to and including the one found), or `False` if the iterator runs out first. Unfortunately, if you ask for values that the iterator will yield in the wrong order, you can easily miss some of them. Here's a simpler example of that:

```
b = iter([1,2,3])
print(1 in b) # prints True
print(3 in b) # prints True, but skipped over 2 to get there
print(2 in b) # prints False, since the iterator is exhausted after seeing 3
```

Comment: I think that's OP's intention. For `a=[1,3,2]; b=[1,2,3]`, `is_subsequence` is supposed to return `False`.